How do I connect uvicorn/fastapi through docker container?
I'm currently building an app that connects to an API server through a script. Here’s how I create posts by connecting to the API server:
            api_url = "http://localhost:8013/posts/"
            print("Post wird erstellt...")
            # Sende POST-Anfrage an FastAPI
            async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
                response = await client.post(api_url, json=post)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    print("Post erfolgreich erstellt.")
                else:
                    print(f"Fehler beim Erstellen des Posts: {response.status_code} {response.text}")

The API request is processed as follows:
....

app = FastAPI()

# Erlaube CORS-Anfragen von http://localhost:3000
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["0.0.0.0"],#"http://telegram-trigger:8014"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

.... 

@app.post("/posts/")
async def create_post(post: Post):
    # Validierung sicherstellen
    if not (
            post.asin and post.title and post.item_link and post.image_url and post.current_price and post.highest_price and post.category
    ):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Not all required information is available.")


Here’s my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  api:
    image: python:3.11-slim  
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app  
    command:  sh -c "pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && python3 -m uvicorn Service.postService:app --reload  --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8013"
    #expose:  
    #  - "8013"
    ports:
      - "8013:8013"  
    environment:
     ....
    networks:
      - app-network

  telegram-trigger:
    image: python:3.11-slim
    working_dir: /app/Service
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: sh -c "cd .. && pip install -r requirements.txt  && PYTHONPATH=. python3 Trigger/telegramTrigger.py"
    depends_on:
      - api
    stdin_open: true  
    tty: true         
    environment:
     ....
    networks:
      - app-network

When I attempt to create a post by sending it to the API, I encounter the following error:
2024-09-20 12:23:05 {'current_price': 129.19, 'highest_price': 319.99, 'discount': '-60%'}
2024-09-20 12:23:05 Post wird erstellt...
2024-09-20 12:23:05 Unhandled exception on new_message_handler
2024-09-20 12:23:05 Traceback (most recent call last):
...
httpx.ConnectError: All connection attempts failed



What could be causing this issue? How can I correctly connect the API server with the Telegram trigger?
I have also specified the service names of the containers as hosts, adjusted the ports, and checked if the script works locally. It functions normally via localhost on my local machine.

Where is the client code running?  Is there any more to the exception you show; for example, is it a "connection refused" type error or something else?  Have you verified the server is actually starting up?

Its all running in a docker compose in the same network. Server is up and running with no problems.

localhost inside a container usually means "the current container", and you need to use a different name in api_url to connect to a different container.  (I'd suggest passing this via an environment variable since it will be different in different setups; local vs. Docker vs. Kubernetes vs...)
